# Problems with multiple trait mixins and Actors

Tags: scala, inheritance, actor, mixins, traits

```
trait A extends Actor {
  private val s = Set[Int]()

  override def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        // case code that modifies s
      }
    }
  }
}

trait B extends Actor {
  private val t = Set[String]()

  override def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        // case code that modifies t
      }
    }
  }
}

val c = new C with A with B //...?
```

What I really want is some sort of auto-combining of `B.act() and C.act()`, but with trait mix-ins, only `B.act()` will be called.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

EDIT: Here is a [half-solution](http://www.kotancode.com/2011/07/19/traits-multiple-inheritance-and-actors-in-scala/) I've found.  I say 'half' because the original traits no longer extend `Actor`, and `C with A with B` needs to be defined as a class as opposed to dynamic mixing-in.  Maybe I should call it a 'quarter-solution'?

Comment: Can a message be received by both `A` and `B` ?

Comment: Sure, why not?  The solution I came up with handles this - if both `A` and `B` have case handlers for a message, the trait that is mixed in later has precedence in resolving.  (Actually, I needed to change `reduce` to `reduceLeft`.)

Comment: Actually, I think I may have misinterpreted your question.  While `A` and `B` **can** both define a case handler for the message, only one of them will actually execute.  But, you **do** have control over which one you want to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could make a trait that forwards the message on to a list of other Actors, so that you don't have to modify `A` or `B`:

```
trait C extends Actor {
  private val acts: Seq[Actor] = Seq(new A{}, new B{})

  override def act() {
    acts foreach (_.start)
    loop {
      react { case x => acts foreach { _ ! x } }
    }
  }
}
```

You could of course leave `acts` abstract or override it with a different set when you instantiate this.

Comment: This isn't possible, `A` and `B` are both traits and can't be instantiated.  I'm assuming you meant `Seq(new C with A, new C with B)`, but note that this leads to *two* copies of `C`, which might be extra memory overhead.  Ignoring that, this is okay, until we have `trait A extends D` and `trait B extends D`.  Now we have *two* copies of the parameters of `D`!  If `A` and `B` both have cases that modify a parameter of `D`, how would we sync them up?

Comment: @jiaweihli sure it's possible: see the code above! `new A{}` is the same as `new Anyref with A`. I don't follow your argument about D; actors shouldn't share mutable state

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of the brace syntax.
`A` and `B` wouldn't share mutable state, since only 1 message handler between all of `A`'s message handlers and `B`'s message handlers resolves at a time.  There should only be 1 copy of all of `D`'s variables.  
The problem with the code you presented is that the message handlers resolve on each instance of the trait - hence multiple copies of `D`.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the Actor class:

```
import actors.Actor

class MixableActor extends Actor {
  protected var acts = List[PartialFunction[Any, Unit]]()

  final override def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        acts.reduce((a, b) => a orElse b)
      }
    }
  }

  final def receive(act: PartialFunction[Any, Unit]) {
    acts = act :: acts
  }
}
```

Sample Code:

```
abstract class Node extends MixableActor {
  ...
}

trait User extends MixableActor {
  val files = scala.collection.mutable.Set[Data]()
}

trait Provider extends User {
  receive({
    case ("provide", file: Data) =>
      provide(file)
  }: PartialFunction[Any, Unit])
}

trait Consumer extends User {
  receive({
    case ("consume", file: Data) =>
      consume(file)
  }: PartialFunction[Any, Unit])
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
val provider = new Node with Provider
val consumer = new Node with Consumer
val provider_and_consumer = new Node with Provider with Consumer
```